# Improving performance of a for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to improve the speed of the following for loop in Matlab. As it is now is incredibly slow. Maybe vectorizing? But one vector slides on the other and constantly changes.

```
for m = 1:size(phi,1) - (constant)/2    
  phi(m) = phi(m).*(mean(conj(phi(1+m:(constant)/2+m))));    
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please define example inputs and outputs.  Specifically, define `phi` and `constant`.  `phi` looks like it's complex-valued as well.

Comment: [movmean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) is your friend.

Comment: I have been too vague in the description.

'Phi' would be a complex vector whereas 'constant' is a constant number (of elements) < than the length of the aforementioned vector phi

Comment: @rahnema1 yes this is what I need! Thanks for the hint